# git global config issue

Tags: git

Somehow, my global git (msysgit) settings for `user.name` and `user.email` (and god knows what else) are set to a recent ex-colleague's details.

When I try and change them i get `could not commit to u://.gitconfig`

If I try and create `u://.gitconfig` through git bash then i get `permission denied`.

```
C:\Users\<My Username>\
```

contains no references to git.

I've tried uninstalling, searching the registry and my file system for all references to git and I can't find any (windows file search is crap though).

What the hell is going on? Why even after reinstalling are this guys details still the global settings???

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The global gitconfig is store at the `$HOME` location (in the Git bash session).
Is it possible you have a `$HOME` (or %HOME% in DOS session) referencing `u:\`.

If so, simply `set HOME=%HOMEPATH%` (if you have `HOMEPATH` defined like in Windows 7), and you should be able to resume accessing/updating *your* global Git configuration.

---

The OP adds:

> my `%HOMEPATH%` is set to `\`, will setting `HOME` to that help?

Well actually no, since `HOME` is not a environment variable usually set by Windows (Xp, Vista or 7).

> fixed it, awesome, set HOME to `c:\users\me`

That is the right fix, although fixing `HOMEPATH` (even if that doesn't directly involve Git) would be also advisable (it shouldn't refer to `u:\`).

Comment: aha! i was assuming u:\ was some git\linux thing but its clearly our network's user profile drive. doh! (i never use that) There must be some network setup error where its not syncing peoples .gitconfig files properly, so said ex-colleague's (probably the only git user) config is ending up in my share. my `%HOMEPATH%` is set to `\\`, will setting `HOME` to that help?

Comment: fixed it, awesome, set `HOME` to c:\users\me

Comment: @Andrew: sorry, just get back from lunch. You have the right fix, even though `HOMEPATH` should also be set at a correct value. I have updated my answer to reflect your comments and solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, but the issue was that my HOME disk was full.