# GITHUB setup - no address associated with name

Tags: git

I'm trying to setup GitHub on my system and I have done all the installation and key setup process:

But during test everything phase getting the following error by command:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
ssh:github.com:no address associated with name
```

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error message. In my case my netbook's wifi switch got bumped and I didn't notice I had no internet connection. So make sure you have internet access if you're getting this error! (duh!)

Answer (score 8):

It means it doesn't found your `HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, and is looking for a `HOME/.ssh/config` file which could have defined the name '`github.com`', as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357232/nbgit-to-remote-host-with-ssh/5357423#5357423).

That usually means you don't have defined what `HOME` is (which isn't defined by default on Windows, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036453/git-global-config-issue/3036514#3036514))

Comment: How come existence of ssh keys is related to not finding remote host?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Because the config file is located in the same directory than the ssh keys. And the error message suggests the IP address isn't return by the DNS (http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2006-December/136983.html). A workaround is to define github.com in an ssh config file, by mentioning its IP address: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357232/nbgit-to-remote-host-with-ssh/5357423#5357423

Comment: Why do you think it's not returned by the DNS? In the post from freebsd list you gave one reads *You get the second message when there is a primary domain name server for the given domain, but it does not return any IP address for your (named) address.* In my case `ssh git@github.com` works but `git clone ssh://git@github.com:piotr-dobrogost/requests.git` raises `ssh: github.com:piotr-dobrogost: no address associated with name` error. Why does ssh client treat semicolon with what follows as a part of host name? I think that's the cause of the problem...

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: I agree with your diagnostic. This must be linked somehow to the syntax of the uri scheme you are using to clone. Would `git clone ssh://git@github.com/piotr-dobrogost/requests.git` works better? Or `git clone ssh://git@github.com/home/piotr-dobrogost/requests.git`?

Comment: Please see my question [“no address associated with name” error when cloning github.com's repo under Windows using ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159522/)

Answer (score 5):

I tried almost everything found on Google related to this question, and nothing seemed to work.
I remembered that Windows has made some updates on 'Windows Defender'. I may seem irrelevant but it is not;

What worked for me was `running Git as Administrator`, which i never did before.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem and the error was that:
I was using the wrong URI, it should be like:

> **ssh -T git@bitbucket.org**

and not as what was copied for cloning

> **ssh -T git@bitbucket.org:*username*/*repo*.git**

Answer (score 1):

If you are working behind proxy, try config ssh to work with the proxy, I encountered the same problem at first and used corkscrew to solve it:
http://www.mtu.net/~engstrom/ssh-proxy.php

Answer (score 0):

I have a client who developed this problem after a Windows 10 update. After a great amount of web searches and trouble shooting, I noticed that his Windows User ID contained spaces, and the error message had said, "S no address associated with name". I noticed that after the space in his name was his middle initial, "S". So I postulated that the user ID was being passed without quotes and was terminating at the first space.

To test my theory, I created a new user ID with no spaces and ran NX Client 3.5.0-7 and it worked.

This also corrected a problem that sprung up with X2Go.

The short answer is, you must not have any spaces in your user name or both NX Client and X2Go will fail.